# Saving Color and Depth data as png to filestream

Tags: c#, stream, kinect

I try to save both color and depth data to separate files as PNGs using PngBitmapEncoder but I get much less depth frames saved than color.

If I save color as Jpeg with JpegBitmapEncoder and depth as PNG using PngBitmapEncoder I get the same amount of frames from both streams.

Can anyone explain me why?

```
private void myKinectSensor_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ColorImageFrame color = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
        {
            if (color != null)
            {
                colorbits = new byte[color.PixelDataLength];
                color.CopyPixelDataTo(colorbits);
                PngBitmapEncoder enc = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(BitmapSource.Create(color.Width, color.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorbits, color.Width * color.BytesPerPixel)));

                if (StartSavingFrames)
                {
                    string temppath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"../output/kinect1/color/", colorcnt.ToString() + ".png");
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(temppath, FileMode.Create);
                    enc.Save(fs);
                    fs.Close();
                    fs = null;
                    colorcnt++;
                }
                else { colorcnt = 0; }
            }
        }
    }



private void myKinectSensor_DepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            using (DepthImageFrame depth = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
            {

                if (depth != null)
                {
                    frame = new short[depth.PixelDataLength];
                    depth.CopyPixelDataTo(frame);
                    for (int i = 0; i < depth.PixelDataLength; i++)
                    {
                        frame[i] = (short)(((ushort)frame[i]) >> 3);
                    }
                    PngBitmapEncoder enc = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                    enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(BitmapSource.Create(depth.Width, depth.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Gray16, null, frame, depth.Width * depth.BytesPerPixel)));

                    if (StartSavingFrames)
                    {
                        string temppath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"../output/kinect1/depth/", cnt.ToString() + ".png");
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(temppath, FileMode.Create);
                        enc.Save(fs);
                        fs.Close();
                        fs = null;
                        cnt++;
                    }
                    else { cnt = 0; }
                }
            }
        }
```

thnx

Comment: could the issue be that the depth frames are sampled at a lower rate than the color frames?

Comment: the depth frames are sampled at the same rate. If I save them with different format i.e. jpeg and png I get the same number of frames.